# How does RPM handle file locations?

Tags: rhel, compiling, rpm

I am trying to create a .spec file for creating mapserver as an rpm package. I am building on an RHEL6 64-bit server.

In rpm files I can use some dir references like `%{_libdir}`,  `%{_bindir}` and  `%{_libexecdir}`. Where are these dir paths configured, and which can be used?

The %files part of my rpm spec looks lige this:

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%doc README COMMITERS GD-COPYING HISTORY.TXT
%doc INSTALL MIGRATION_GUIDE.txt
%doc symbols tests
%doc fonts
%{_bindir}/*
%{_libdir}/libmapserver*.so
%{_libexecdir}/mapserv
```

but when I run my build I get the errors:

```
File not found by glob: /home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/lib64/libmapserver*.so
File not found: /home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/libexec/mapserv
```

It seems like the files that are missing are insted located in

```
/home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/lib/libmapserver-6.2.1.so
/home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/lib/libmapserver.la
/home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/lib/libmapserver.so
/home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libmapserver-6.2.1.so.debug
/home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libmapserver.so.debug

/home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/usr/bin/mapserv
/home/kfadm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mapserver-6.2.1-3.x86_64/var/www/cgi-bin/mapserv
```

How do I fix the rpm spec to find the files at the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem stems from the fact that RHEL wants 64-bit libraries to be installed to the /usr/lib64 directory, rather than the default /usr/lib directory.

mapserver 6.2.1 uses autoconf, and includes a --libdir option. In your .spec file modify the ./configure command: `%configure --libdir=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_libdir}`

Comment: I'm looking at the Makefile produced by a `configure` run on mapserver-6.2.1, and as best I can tell, the problem lies in how autoconf detects the value for @libdir@. The easiest workaround is to add `--libdir=/usr/lib64` to your configure directive in your specfile. There's a reference to a .m4 solution at http://gnu-autoconf.7623.n7.nabble.com/Autoconf-and-64-bit-Systems-td11943.html, but that's a bit over my head.

Comment: @John thanks for pointing out the version... I was looking at 6.4.0 which transitioned to CMake. Modified to make sense for the specific version Jesper is looking for

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem because of missing install command to create that specific directory. Once i have added the install command under `%install`, the `rpm` generated successfully

```
install -m 755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_sysconfdir}/php.d
```